# How to call a method from a button in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a button in C#:

```
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    StartService();
}
```

and I try to call the method:

```
public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    try
    {
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

        service.Start();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
    }
    catch
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if the call method is correct on the button

Comment: Why are you not sure? Are you getting errors or exceptions? And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to provide the parameters for startservice. At the moment, Im very doubtful this would compile.

Eg

```
StartService("MyService",20000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the `StartService` seems to take two parameters: string and integer and when calling it you aren't passing any. The compiler is probably already telling you this. Generally reading compiler error messages helps.

Also when calling a static method you might want to specify the class name where this method is defined (for more clarity):

```
SomeClass.StartService("some name of a service", 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your program won't compile because the `StartService` method is expecting two parameters (`serviceName` and `timeoutMilliseconds`).